Добавление дискового раздела в Fedora
Здравствуйте, у меня половина ssd под линукс, другая под виндовс. Я освободил 200гб от винды, как мне теперь примонтировать их к линуксу?
jokkeu@192:~$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
zram0       252:0    0     8G  0 disk [SWAP]
nvme0n1     259:0    0 476.9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   100M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 475.8G  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0   999M  0 part 
nvme1n1     259:5    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme1n1p1 259:6    0    16M  0 part 
├─nvme1n1p2 259:7    0   492G  0 part 
├─nvme1n1p3 259:8    0     1G  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme1n1p4 259:9    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─nvme1n1p5 259:10   0 242.1G  0 part /home
                                      /

В gparted тоже не получается сделать, я могу "прикастить" ее к brtfs или ext4, но расширить "fedora" так и не получается.


Эти разделы на разных дисках? Тут один вариант, это либо переустановка, либо монтирование в какой либо путь, например /bin

Перезагрузиться в LiveCD/LiveUSB и переместить все три раздела влево
